# Как убрать второй скролл

Tags: html, bootstrap, окно

У меня на сайте при открытии модального окна появляется второй скролл,как убрать его?И как исправить дергание сайта при открытии модальных окон?

Дело в том что я хотел исправить проблему модальных окон(дергание сайта при открытии модального окна).Поставил принудительный скролл:

```
html{
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Дергание пропало,появился второй скролл рядом с основным.Как его убрать чтобы и скролл пропал(чтобы основной остался) и сайт не дергался при открытии модального окна?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, один скролл принадлежит `html`, а второй - `body`.

Могу предположить, что где-то прописано что-то типа `html, body { height:100% }`. Попробуй поменять `html` на `body` в твоём варианте из вопроса.

Для более конкретного ответа данных недостаточно.